# No library support DOM manipulation as shown by jQuery equivalent

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm spoiled by my libraries especially jQuery. What I want to do with pure JavaScript alone is the equivalent of:

```
$('#id').mouseover(function(){
var wide = $(this).width();
var high = $(this).height();

$('#id2').css({"position":wide+'px' high+'px'}).show();
});
$('#id').mouseout(function(){$('#id2').hide();});
```

My ultimate goal is to have when ID is hovered over have it show ID2 at the bottom right of the ID element. Unfortunately I'd be able to get this all set up quick in jQuery and I am seriously spoiled by it, but I have a direct need to do this without library support such as jQuery. Ideally I would like to use a class in replacement of ID's but from what I gather JavaScript alone doesn't support that outright.

Comment: If you can do it in jQuery, you can do it in javascript, since jQuery is javascript.

Comment: You're using alot of jQuery methods which highly use cross-browser switches (which is the ultimate goal of jQuery, beeing compatible with much browser as possible). So of course you can re-write this in vanilla js, but the code will blow-up like a magnitude of 10x or more if you're doing it right.

Comment: Yes I know its possible via JavaScript alone as thats what all the libraries are composed of. However I am spoiled by the libraries and the short cuts that exist in making it so I can rapidly develop the concept as well as be cross browser friendly. However I am not allowed to use any library in this concept so I am a little stuck on how to approach otherwise.

Comment: @chris: a good start is to look into the lib. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the styling of your divs of course, so I've stuck some sample HTML in for good measure.

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 200px; width: 200px;">
    <div id="first" style="position: absolute">
        11111111111111111
    </div>
    <div id="second" style="position: absolute; display: none;">
        22222222222222222
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var first = document.getElementById("first");
    first.onmouseover = function () {
        var left = this.offsetLeft + this.offsetWidth;
        var top = this.offsetTop + this.offsetHeight;

        var second = document.getElementById("second");
        second.style.left = left + "px";
        second.style.top = top + "px";
        second.style.display = "block";
    }
    first.onmouseout = function () {
        document.getElementById("second").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```